# What enables the Android Eclipse LogCat?

Tags: android, eclipse, logcat

The LogCat window is open. Sometimes LogCat displays Log messages, sometimes it does not, with or without the physical target attached. Is there an enable/disable Log somewhere in the debug environment?

Comment: Do you have the device/emulator selected in the tree-table in the upper-left of DDMS?

Comment: I experienced instability with Eclipse & logcat. Sometimes you also need to hit one of the Icons for the error level (V,E,W) first until something shows up, even though device etc. is connected properly. I therefore prefer to run logcat via command line, appears more stable ('adb shell logcat').

Comment: The ddms standalone application (in SDK's tools folder) is also stable and my standard choice

Comment: If you're having a problem seeing your device in DDMS (and therefore also in LogCat, and it's a Nexus <X> or similar, it might be because you need to install additional drivers. See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11533228/not-seeing-nexus7-in-eclipses-android-devices

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I also have this problem within Eclipse.  If you are lucky enough to not care about what has already been written to LogCat, you can click the "Clear Log" button on the top right next to the V,D,I,W,E buttons.

If you select the device and clear the log, I've found that the output is stable (at least until it fills up again).

Comment: Sometimes just selecting the device (on "Devices" view) does the trick.

Comment: Be careful, "Device Management" view does not direct the interface, only the "Devices" view does.

Answer (score 9):

I was having the same problem when trying to show logs on LogCat using the emulator. I solved this selecting "Reset adb" on the "Device" tab of DDMS.

Answer (score 6):

type this :

> adb kill-server
>   adb start-server
>   adb logcat

Answer (score 4):

There is a known bug with logcat on Eclipse, it could be what you're experiencing:
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2752

A suggested solution is to unplug the device and clear the logs, then start again

Answer (score 3):

This happens to me when I work on an emulator and also my phone plug to the computer. My phone's log do not show on logcat. To solve the problem I close the emulator.

Answer (score 3):

To disable the LogCat view from automatically appearing, deselect the following in Preferences:

Android > LogCat > Display logcat view when there are messages from an application in the workspace

Answer (score 2):

If changing the Log level does not displays the log messages, close the debug perspective and then reopen it using the shortcut key or (Window -> Open Perspective -> debug), in Eclipse. This should surely resolve the issue of missing log messages.

cheers

Answer (score 1):

I usually have this problem too. I found that what happens is that the LogCat is clearing the view as fast as the log messages are coming in, so I can't see anything.

What helped me was to change the log level. e.g. if it was at Debug, change to Verbose and then back to Debug. LogCat returns to normal and allows the logs to persist.

That worked for me, but YMMV.

P.S. Also check that your device is actually connected and 'online'. Sometimes, the device can go offline and LogCat can't print anything then.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this next time it happens.

Answer (score 1):

click on DDMS then click on debug button (the bug icon next to run button)

Answer (score 1):

To start, I am running Eclipse Indigo on a Mac OSX 10.7.4.

To keep the Logcat from dying and having to restart Eclipse each time I have been pausing Logcat and then right clicking and quitting the emulator from the dock. This does not work if you pause and click the close button in the emulator window.

Once the emulator is started again, unpause the Logcat and it seems to function properly. Make sure that the app has loaded completely, as shown by Console, before you close the window otherwise this does not work.

I have not figured out why this works yet. I have not had the chance to test this on my Windows machine.

Answer (score 0):

If none of the proposed methods works, try deactivating and activating developer options on your phone. Do not forget to re-enable USB debugging!