# Not seeing Nexus7 in Eclipse's Android Devices

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ADB dosn't recognize my Galaxy Nexus - Win7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8801829/adb-dosnt-recognize-my-galaxy-nexus-win7)

I'm not seeing my Nexus7 listed in Eclipse's DDMS Devices.

DDMS and "adb devices" from the console show my G1 android phone, but not the Nexus7.

Usb Debugging is enabled on both phones, Eclipse is up to date as far as I can tell, Android SDK's Google-USB-rev6

When I plugged in the N7 USB, I did see the Windows7 driver installed, and can browse files on it from file manager.

MTP/PTP made no difference (MTP drivers from Microsoft Update, none for PTP)

"Select debug app" in Developer Options shows nothing.

"Unknown sources" is checked.

Tried different Usb port, toggled Usb Debugging.

Comment: The answers to this question are out of date. The best way to install Asus Nexus 7 USB drivers is to directly get the inf from [ASUS](http://support.asus.com/Download.aspx?SLanguage=en&m=Nexus+7&p=20&s=16) and manually install them through the device manager.

Comment: This question applies to the Nexus 7 (from Asus). The question quoted as a duplicate is for the Galaxy Nexus (from Samsung). Voted to re-open.

Comment: +1 for XMO.  When Windows 7 said it was installing the driver, I foolishly believed it!

Comment: Another thing to try (worked for me), on the Nexus 7 pull down the notification bar and switch the "Connect as" to camera. Windows 7 then installed another driver and things started working as expected. Described here in more detail: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=41532394&postcount=16

Comment: In case you came here looking for an answer on how to activate USB debugging for the NEW Nexus 7 on Windows 8, check out this link: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/hanuk/archive/2013/05/24/enabling-usb-debugging-for-nexus-7-on-windows-8.aspx

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Heres what I did to get it working:

1. I happened to already have ADB drivers for the Samsung Galaxy Nexus installed, if you don't, you need to download those.
2. Plug in the Nexus 7 and windows will find 2 drivers automatically, but won't find any for "Nexus"
3. Go to Device Manager, under "Other Devices" you'll see "Nexus" with the yellow exclamation mark, Right Click>Upate Drivers>Let me choose>Let me pick form device drivers on my computer.
4. Scroll down to "SAMSUNG Android Phone" (Again, the Galaxy Nexus drivers should be installed already, if not, find them), and choose the driver for "Android ADB Interface"
5. Click "Next", and the device should pop up in Eclipse.

It worked for me, at least.

Comment: Looks promising.  I was looking into using the drivers in this root toolkit, without actually rooting. They seem to be designed for the Asus Nexus7, though not from Asus: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1766475

Comment: Got it working by downloading and running the root toolkit from (http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1766475), just far enough to put the Nexus7 drivers in a directory I could point to, and "Update Driver" for the "MTP device" manually. Similar to what user1023127 did with Samsung-Nexus drivers, but I didn't test those.

Now seeing asus-nexus device in Eclips/DDMS, and was able to run an app on the tablet.

Comment: The entry I selected was "Android phone" rather then "Samsung Android phone".  Seems to work.

Comment: This answer worked for me. I also find that I have to repeat the process from time-to-time

Comment: My Device Manager wouldn't show a *Nexus 7* item until I uninstalled the ADB Interface item first (deleting driver files). Then when I plugged in the Nexus 7 it appeared in Device Manager and I could follow your instructions from there. Just mentioning it in case anyone else has the same issue.

Comment: As @Tom Said  "Android phone" worked,make sure to install "USB Composite Interface" from Compatible Hardware list and sure need a system restart.

Comment: I had to change the connection to camera and after that to update the driver. When it was connected as media device, win 8 wouldn't let me update the driver.

Comment: Drivers got successfully installed and still device is not recognized by DDMS? Here is what worked for me: Go to device's notification bar >> Tap on "Connected as a media device" >> select Camera (PTP) option.

Answer (score 24):

This is how I finally got it to work.

1. Download the naked adb driver:

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1766220

1. Unzip it
2. Open device manager
3. Find Nexus 7 in portable devices
4. Right click and select Update Driver Software
5. A couple clicks and typing lets you enter a path for your driver, enter wherever you put the unzipped naked driver
6. Now when the device is plugged in it shows up as Android Phone which seems like we are getting somewhere.
7. Reboot (I got frustrated because still not seeing my device in ADB DEVICES--might not be necessary)
8. Device manager, right click Android Phone/Google Nexus 7 ADB Interface, Update Driver Software
9. I selected USB Composite device but don't remember exactly how since I can't get back to that screen
10. ADB DEVICES shows my device now!  (Also Eclipse)
11. When I go into Device Manager the driver for my nexus 7 is "Google Nexus 7 ADB Interface" provided by Google, Inc., dated 12/6/2010, version 4.0.0.0 and it is not digitally signed

Hope this helps someone, why doesn't ASUS have a downloadable driver on their website?

Comment: It took me a while to figure out why non of the solutions regarding "USB debugging" and driver versions worked for me until I found this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17218953/nexus-4-does-not-show-the-rsa-dialog-when-connecting-usb-in-debug-mode
Seems you also need to update to the latest version of the SDK! Hope this helps some of the people who have been installing every possible driver without any luck ;)

Answer (score 2):

I wasted a bit of time getting my Nexus 7 USB/debug connection to work. In between poor documentation and lack of feedback from Windows 7 drivers, I missed a subtlety in the setup on the device. Enabling the debugging features on the device proper is actually two modifications, not one:

Go to Settings -> Developer options

Enable the developer settings overall by toggling the button on the top right, which enables other settings on the page. I skim read the rest of the options, and figured I was done.

Then enable the option "USB debugging", subtitled "Debug mode when USB is connected". If you don't switch this on, your drivers will register, but never do anything, or tell you why not... i.e. you're device won't even be listed when you run "adb devices", and Windows won't enable any of the standard USB file access features either.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a 32-bit or 64-bit version of Windows?  I too have the same problem and have had success using the same device on Macintosh.

My experience with drivers and 64-bit windows has been hit or miss since the Nexus One.

Answer (score 1):

The correct driver now appears to install to [Android SDK]\google-usb_driver instead of just usb_driver. I still have both directories but once I pointed the driver update at the Google one it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Use a mac?

I have the same exact problem and have spent hours trying to get this to work on my Windows 7 laptop, I have messed around with the Universal Naked Driver (0.7) and tried to use the driver install tool in the Nexus Root Toolkit (1.5.2).  No help.  I also searched Asus for a driver (nothing but a manual there).  I also made sure all my Android SDK software was up to date.

When I try on a Mac it does show up! It still doesn't show up on my Windows 7 laptop using "adb devices", or in Eclipsed under DDMS.  A galaxy nexus running jelly bean shows up just fine on the laptop.

Device Manager > Portable Devices > Nexus 7 > driver properties: Microsoft, 6/21/2006, 6.17600.16385

The Samsung Galaxy Nexus phone that works is using a Samsung driver

Comment: Can you hexedit some generic android driver to match it's VID, or will that break driver signing in a problematic way?   Running linux on your existing hardware would be cheaper than getting a Mac. Out of curiousity, what is it's VID?

Comment: I see that driver too (Nexus7/PortableDevice/6.17600.16385) under this MTP Device, but there's another Device Function listed for it (Nexus/OtherDevices/..) with a warning icon, for which there's no driver installed.

Comment: I am happy others have got this to work, I am still stuck.  64-bit version of Windows, running a Lenovo ThinkPad, have tried all three USB ports, can anyone tell me what driver is actually working for them?  And where in device manager their device is showing and how?  I have tried every combination possible with the root kit.

Comment: The device shows up as recognized in device manager, but doesn't appear in DDMS.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working by downloading and running the root toolkit from (http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1766475), just far enough to put the Nexus7 drivers in a directory I could point to, and "Update Driver" for the "MTP device" manually.   Similar to what user1023127 did below with Samsung-Nexus drivers, but I didn't test those.

Now seeing asus-nexus device in Eclips/DDMS,  and was able to run an app on the tablet.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm HappyFunBall's solution. Do not use the automatic driver install in Nexus Root Toolkit; complete Step 4 of the manual install and stop.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you need drivers.

Do what I do:

Publish your app to your computer. 
Then In google play download Bluetooth File Transfer app (or any other file manager). 
Copy your app to a folder inside your nexus 7.
Open Bluetooth File Transfer and click on your app.
And finally click ok to install.

You'll have to do this until Asus releases some User Friendly Interface.

Comment: It is this clicking and stuff which is eliminated once you start using USB Debugging.