# Asus Nexus 7 not recognized by Android dev tools via adb

Tags: android, adb, nexus-7

Problem:
Asus Nexus 7 not recognized by adb when correctly installed and connected

Setup:
Asus Nexus 7 tablet
Windows 7 64 bit OS

Steps taken:

1. Installed 64 bit Java JDK (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html)
2. Installed Android SDK (http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)
3. Installed Google USB driver (http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html)
4. Set tablet to USB debugging mode

In the Windows Device Manager, the Nexus is recognized as an Android Device via Android Composite ADB Interface. The device status indicates it is connected and working properly, running driver version 7.0.0.1 (8/27/12 update) from Google.

However, when I run `adb devices` at the command prompt (in the sdk/platform-tools directory), the Nexus does not come up as an attached device - the list is empty.

Does anyone have any insight on what the problem might be? I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling all drivers, restarting the computer each time. I have tried a variety of usb ports and cables, as well as switching between MTP and PTP connections with no success.

Comment: Tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11533228/not-seeing-nexus7-in-eclipses-android-devices

Comment: yes; doesn't solve problem

Comment: Have you enabled USB Error logging on the device? If not, this is your issue

Comment: @Matt + for outlining how to solve my problem. I hope you got yours working.

Comment: This link was not referenced yet in answers and this is the best one I found: http://www.theandroidsoul.com/nexus-7-2013-drivers-installation-guide/

Comment: The proper solution is to go into the Device Manager, uninstall+delete the driver for the device, then plug it back in and let it find the right driver. See nimizen's answer \/

Answer (score 49):

Hey I found a solution to this via `mkh` at
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/0-RzE0v-G3k

Try this (as quoted from the above source)

> When the Nexus 7 is plugged in there is a persistent notification that
>   indicates "CONNECT AS / Media Device (MTP)". In this state adb devices
>   will not show the Nexus. Not exactly obvious why, but I you select the
>   second option "Camera (PTP)" the device is available for debugging.
>   This choice is persistent, and I'm guessing that with a band new
>   device it will connect as MTP until told otherwise

Comment: Doesn't seem relevant. Debugging works fine for me in MTP mode (Android 4.2.2).

Comment: This worked for me with both a Nexus 7 and a Samsung Galaxy S4. After unchecking the MTP checkbox and checking the Camera (PTP) checkbox, I was able to debug an app on both within Eclipse.

Comment: Weird, but this was the solution for me as well - changing from MTP to PTP.

Comment: I had to change the connection to camera and after that to update the driver. When it was connected as media device, win 8 wouldn't let me update the driver.

Comment: This worked for me, it recognizes it as a Camera (PTP) on Windows 8 using Eclipse Kepler.

Comment: This is a workaround. While it worked, I believe nimizen's solution is The Right Way to do this.

Answer (score 35):

An important note about Nexus 7: There is no option for USB debugging readily available in the device Settings for 4.2.

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1989777

"Open Settings, then go to phone details (where u can see kernel, Android-version etc) then just tap your Build number 'JOP40C' 7 times!"

This sounds ludicrous, but after I did this, the developer options unlocked and I was able to see my nexus 7 in Eclipse (mac, Mountain Lion) for debugging.

Comment: yes I laughed when I first read it, and the guys in the office laughed when I showed them it worked. This is correct.

Comment: this should be accepted as the correct answer. Goodness, I literally laughed at the toasts "You are 2 more steps from being a developer." LOL! so the apps I've deployed on the play store didn't make me?

Comment: I did this an I'm still not seeing the device in eclipse. I tried restarted the device and eclipse. What else would I need to do?

Comment: I did that and got message like "u r developer" but device is nt detecting in eclipse

Comment: As you said, it sounds ludicrous, but worked for me. @Braj, you still need to go to Developer options in Settings and enable debugging/installing etc. Once I did that, eclipse detected the device.

Comment: This isn't the answer, because Matt said they had already enabled developer mode.

Answer (score 23):

In my case when I got an empty list using "adb devices" I found that the device manager showed the Nexus 7 tablet under 'other devices' with that dreaded yellow exclamation point indicating that the driver was not installed correctly. Why Windows recognized part of the tablet file system, I don't know. In any case I manually updated the driver to the google usb driver in android-sdks\extras\google.

Then adb gave me the following:

C:\Users\Brian\android-sdks\platform-tools>adb devices

List of devices attached

015d25785b601611        device

instead of a blank. I hope this doesn't mess anything else up but I can now talk to the device.

Comment: Just had to help our testing lady solve this on Windows 8. Uninstalled drivers from device manager (also tick box to remove drivers from pc)> let windows install its own driver > then in device manager update drivers to these from android-sdk/extra/google folder. After that Nexus 7 was working fine

Comment: I found my Nexus 7 device with the yellow exclamation point in the device manager list. From there I clicked on it's icon to install a driver for this device and then navigated to the android-sdks\extras\google folder when Windows asked me if it should attempt to find the driver online or locally on my computer. This solved the issue and I am now able to see the device when I write "adb devices" in the terminal.

Comment: I just updated the driver and it works fine. Android immediately shown a fingerprint of my computer on Nexus that I had to accept.

Comment: I had this exact same problem with the Nexus 7 (2013), Windows 7 64-bit. Windows was detecting it in Media and Camera mode, but showed up in Device Manager just as described here. Making sure the Google driver was installed with the SDK Manager and then manually pointing to that driver did the trick.  The tablet does also ask for a confirmation, but now it works!  Thanks!

Comment: I had to change the connection to camera and after that to update the driver. When it was connected as media device, win 8 wouldn't let me update the driver.

Answer (score 14):

Had the same issue, Windows 7 32-bit; visited the site that Graham linked in his answer but wasn't happy running PTP (though it did work).  Following the steps on another post belonging to the same thread sorted it (I can now connect as MTP); again, a direct quote from https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/0-RzE0v-G3k (thanks sfoucher!):

> 1. uninstall the driver in the device manager with option "delete the driver software for this device"
> 2. reconnect the Nexus tablet
> 3. let windows install a default driver which will be inadequate
> 4. uninstall again the device in the device manager with the option  "delete the driver software for this device"
> 5. let windows try to find the driver, this process will fail
> 6. go back to the device manager and right click the failed device and update driver
> 7. choose the driver location in the android sdk directory (android/extra/google/usb_driver)

I should add that after step 5 I had Nexus 7 listed under Portable devices looking OK but had another Nexus 7 entry under Other Devices to which I applied the driver.  My Nexus 7 now appears OK in ADB and Eclipse.  In device manager I have Nexus 7 under Portable Devices and Android Composite ADB Interface under Android Device.

Comment: In my case, the second time around, windows actually picked the right driver on its own.

Comment: I have been tried many solutions but not work. The above solution help me debugging in Andorid studio by real device (my Asus Zenfone C).

Answer (score 8):

I too had the same issue on windows 7 64 bit.

Following thing solved my problem.

1. Connect the Nexus 7 and tap on Settings-About Tablet-Build version 7 times.!
2. This will install basic driver for windows
3. Now, tap on connected as media device(MTP) icon, but you will need to change it as Camera device then
4. Go to device manager on windows, select Nexus 7 and then update the drivers using the driver avaliable on this link http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html - This will install a driver ( You can use it with this one)
5. Now tap on Connected as Camera device and change it to media device - This will install one more driver and you are ready to go.!

Answer (score 4):

i was having the same problem and my solution was to download the device driver from Asus. Below is the link.

http://support.asus.com/Download.aspx?SLanguage=en&m=Nexus+7&p=28&s=2

Answer (score 2):

That's how I solved this issue with a different device.

- Download the drivers, unzip in a folder https://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html#top
- With your tablet plugged, go to System -> Device admin -> Android Device -> Properties -> Details -> Hardware ID
- You'll find something like USB/VID_XXXX&PID_YYYY, we will need those XXXX and YYYY later.
- Go to the folder you put your drivers and edit the file **android_winusb.inf** manually.
- Add this:

  ;MY PHONE
  %SingleBootLoaderInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_XXXX&PID_YYYY
  %CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_XXXX&PID_YYYY&MI_01
- Save the file
- Go back to device manager and try to update the driver with this one. (Driver -> Update driver -> Search in my computer -> Choose from a list -> Use disk).

That worked for me on a [Quechua Phone](http://www.quechuaphone.com/).

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me is downloading the USB driver from the ASUS website:

http://support.asus.com/Download.aspx?SLanguage=en&m=Nexus+7&p=28&s=2

(you have to select the OS, which sometimes doesn't work, e.g. on the link Google returns when searching for "nexus 7 driver"). In that case, click on "Drivers and Download" and search for "Nexus 7". That gets me a page with a working OS selection.

Answer (score 1):

I am using Windows 8 and the only thing that worked for me was the Nexus Root Toolkit 1.6.3 where I done the Full driver configuration Guide ... but I didn't follow the instructions there I went to step 2 and only installed the  Signed drivers.

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1766475

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. For me the newer version of adb is required to connect to the Nexus 7 i.e. to have the Nexus 7 ask me to "Allow USB debugging?"

In short:

Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.31 - Works

Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.29 - Does not work

Comment: This was also my finding.  There was a mismatch in the adb/usb driver version.  It would not work until I updated adb and the usb driver.  Admittedly I hadn't run the SDK Manager for a long time.

Answer (score 1):

Download the latest android usb drivers from

http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html#top

And then manually install these driver using Device Manager. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I had faced two issues:

1. Nexus 7 not visible to eclipse/adb when connected over usb on windows 7 64-bit using latest Jelly Bean sdk
2. It was not showing in the 'My Computer' >> 'Portable Devices' list.

Ultimately, I found that it is an issue with the driver. Steps to resolve the issue - Open Device Manager, Uninstall the current driver (along with delete option set to yes), disconnect the device, reconnect it again, let windows install the default driver it wants, and then installed the google sdk driver again. It worked this time.

Above tells me that there is some issue with default driver and therefore, you have to delete it and re-install it. Now, it is visible in eclipse/adb and also showing in 'My Computer' also.

./hemant.virmani

Answer (score 0):

Install Google usb driver from SDK Manager.
Later go to Device Manager, under "Other Devices" you'll see "Nexus" with the yellow exclamation mark. Right Click>Update Drivers>Let me choose>Let me pick from device drivers on my computer. Select android-sdk folder and click ok.
This solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

Another option is if windows updates are turned totally off on your PC. In this case even if you download the USB driver & try update it manually as described above it will not work. The only way in this case is enabling windows updating drivers automatically. Once you enabled this, remove the non-working driver from device manager & connect you tablet to the PC via USB cable. The drivers will be automatically downloaded & installed by Windows.
This way worked on my Windows 7 PC.

Answer (score 0):

After downloading the USB driver using the SDK manager, you can speed up the search for the new driver by telling Windows to look in the C:\Users\jdaehn\AppData\Local\Android\android-studio\sdk\extras\ folder (and sub-folders, in my case the drivers were in C:\Users\jdaehn\AppData\Local\Android\android-studio\sdk\extras\google\usb_driver)

Answer (score 0):

From website below

http://www.asus.com/Tablets_Mobile/Nexus_7/HelpDesk_Download/

Download USB -> Nexus 7 USB driver for Windows

[image]

Unzip

Then follow the directions on this website below:

http://www.theandroidsoul.com/nexus-7-2013-drivers-installation-guide/

An Example for step #5, point it at this location:

C:\Users\Gene\Documents\Computer Setup (Installed Programs)\Asus Nexus Device Drivers\usb_driver

Answer (score 0):

Download universal windows adb driver(Koush). Worked for me for windows pc's. http://www.koushikdutta.com/post/universal-adb-driver