# Android. Debugging on a real device (Nexus 7)

Tags: android, eclipse, adb, adt

People, help please. Do not know what to do. Installed Android SDK, all as it should. Create the first application, the normal code, compilation errors does not. But to test this whole thing on the emulator - "hellish inferno."

I have an Asus Nexus 7 (tablets). How do I debug it? Eclipse and adb no means see it.

**p.s.** Yes, of course I brought the tablet to "developer" and check the "Debugging USB" 
**ps2.** Yes, I put a USB into the computer. 
**p.s.3.** Wood poses with SDK Manager (also tried to put the official website ASUS)

Comment: What do you mean? Your tablet can't be detected by ADB?

Comment: Make sure all drivers are installed

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This appears to be answered here:  [Not seeing Nexus7 in Eclipse's Android Devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11533228/not-seeing-nexus7-in-eclipses-android-devices).

Specifically note the comment to the top rated answer where it suggests getting the driver directly from ASUS [here](http://support.asus.com/Download.aspx?SLanguage=en&m=Nexus%207&p=20&s=16).

Comment: That link didnt work for me, but this one did http://www.asus.com/Tablets_Mobile/Nexus_7/#support_Download_8

Answer (score 1):

cracked it after 2 hours...

1. download this usb driver:
   http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/EeePAD/nexus7/usb_driver_r06_windows.zip

2.go to the device manager , right click the nexus device and choose properties,
 choose "hardware" and then choose update your driver , choose manualy and pick the folder 
you opend the zip file to and press apply.

3.open your setting in nexus . go to : "about the device" , at the bottom of the page and press it 7 times .

4.open the developers menu and enable debug with usb.
5.finally press storage from the setting menu and click the menu that apears at the top left corner.
press the connect usb to the computer, choose the second option (PTP).

that should do the trick , they couldn't make it more simple than that...

Comment: Thank you. I hope it'll help all in future.

Comment: great! i'm glad it helped you out

Answer (score 1):

From website below

http://www.asus.com/Tablets_Mobile/Nexus_7/HelpDesk_Download/

Download USB -> Nexus 7 USB driver for Windows

[image]

Unzip

Then follow the directions on this website below:

http://www.theandroidsoul.com/nexus-7-2013-drivers-installation-guide/

An Example for step #5, point it at this location:

C:\Users\Gene\Documents\Computer Setup (Installed Programs)\Asus Nexus Device Drivers\usb_driver