# Eclipse is not picking up my Android devices target API

Tags: android, eclipse, device

I realize this has been asked before but none have been able to help me, I want to use my Nexus 7 with my pre-existing Android project but when I attempt to use it Eclipse doesn't pick up it's target.

-I've updated my related drivers.

-The Android composite ADB interface is up to date.

-It works on the device I was previously using (HTC Desire S).


**UPDATE**


It does not pick up the target when Iconnect it as PTP and MTP + in both it registers the state as offline.

Comment: do you see the device in adb?

Comment: Yes, the device shows up, all apart from the target, so I cannot run it, I wanted to post a picture but my reputation is to low.

Comment: Did you update your SDK version as well?

Comment: SDK and API's are up to date.

Answer (score 0):

the most common reasons for the device not showing up as a target.

1) "Eclipse needs to be restarted".

2) the driver for the device is not installed properly.

3) the target api/version code is not compatible

try

1) to plug the phone into a different usb port. (that sometimes refreshes the driver)

2) create a empty project that is compatible with your android version and see if it picks 
up your device (if it does that means you have to update the targetSdk for your project).

---

if all fails restart eclipse a few times and keep your fingers crossed.

Comment: I tried a new project with a build target of 4.1 that had no effect, I'm using the only working USB port and I've tried restarting Eclipse, no luck.
It does pick up my Device just not the target, which prevents me from running it.

Comment: then follow this instead of changing usb port http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=34658752&postcount=8

Answer (score 0):

Follow this tutorial.

If you like playing around with your Android device (e.g. rooting or installing custom ROMs), then you probably are familiar with Android’s ‘USB debugging mode’. However, USB debugging mode is really intended only for developers and people who don’t know what they are doing may accidentally enable it and put their device at risk. This is why starting in Android 4.2 Jelly Bean, Google has hidden the ability to enable USB debugging mode. If you want to know how to enable USB debugging mode in Android 4.2 and higher, this guide will show you exactly how to do that.

The following steps work on all Android devices running Android 4.2 and higher. That includes Nexus 4, Nexus 10, Nexus 7, Galaxy Nexus, and any other device.
How to find and turn on USB debugging mode in Android 4.2 and higher

To see the option for USB debugging mode in Android 4.2 or higher, do the following:

```
Open up your device’s “Settings”. This can be done by pressing the Menu button while on your home screen and tapping “System settings”
Now scroll to the bottom and tap “About phone” or “About tablet”.
At the “About” screen, scroll to the bottom and tap on “Build number” seven times.
    Make sure you tap seven times. If you see a “You are now a developer!” message pop up, then you know you have done it correctly.
```

Done! By tapping on “Build number” seven times, you have unlocked USB debugging mode on Android 4.2 and higher. You can now enable/disable it whenever you desire by going to “Settings” -> “Developer Options” -> “Debugging” ->” USB debugging”.
Conclusion

That was easy. The best part is you only have to do the tap-build-number-seven-times once. After you do it once, USB debugging has been unlocked and you can enable or disable at your leisure.

If you alrady done, 
Check if this solution helps [Not seeing Nexus7 in Eclipse's Android Devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11533228/not-seeing-nexus7-in-eclipses-android-devices)