# Nexus 4 does not show the RSA dialog when connecting USB in debug mode

Tags: android, dialog, usb, rsa

I did the factory reset, and my computer is newly installed.
I enabled the USB debuging, and connect to the computer. It shows the drivers are installed successfully, and i can see so in the device manager.
But the phone does not show the RSA dialog to comfirm the connection, and in the DDMS, it is offline...
My nexus is official android 4.2.2
Has anyone met this issue? Please give advice! thanks!

/************Update*************/
I tried on my office computer. When connected to the office computer, the dialog, which shows the RSA key fingerprint, pops up. But as i tried this on my home computer, no dialog and merely the notifications on the bar.

Answer (score 7):

Using terminal (cmd in windows), go into sdk/platform-tools folder.

Then launch `adb devices` command.

You should see "Starting daemon" and then the Fingerprint popup will appear on your device.

If does not, unplug usb cable, restart pc, plug the cable to phone and try again launching adb command.

Answer (score 3):

For Linux `adb kill-server` or if adb is running in sudo `sudo adb kill-server`

On android device Settings > Developer options > Revoke USB debug authorizations
USB Debug option is still Enabled

Connect the device to linux mach.
sudo adb devices

check RSA Fingerprint popup is seen

Comment: that is just the theory. tried it 30 times, i still get shown an unauthorized device.

Comment: Worked for me after running 'kill-server'

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have the Android SDK Platform-tools updated to 16.0.1. I ran into this problem after update to 4.2.2 and updating adb and platform-tools solved the problem. The steps are neatly explained here -> http://www.thekirankumar.com/blog/2013/02/17/how-to-fix-adb-device-offline-issue-after-android-4-2-2-upgrade/

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same issue on my mac book and solved it by quitting out of Parallels desktop.

The problem manifested for both a Motorola Atrix and brand new 11/14/2014 Galaxy S5.

The issue seemed to be that the sequence

1. Connect USB Mac to Phone
2. Get challenged to use this phone for USB debugging
3. Confirm the RSA key

Was being interrupted at the device recognition level.

For me, the issue was Parallels Desktop stopping the handshake to ask if I wanted to connect this device to my Mac or Windows instance.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had to make sure the phone was connected as "charging".  For some reason "file sharing" didn't work.

Answer (score -1):

You need to enable the Developer Option by going to Settings-->About Phone --> Tap 7 Times on Build Number Option.

Then open command prompt - Check the adb version by typing "adb version" if it shows 1.0.31 then you are good to go else update your adt version to 1.0.31 or higher.

After doing the above step-- type adb devices - It will show device offline and on you phone the RSA Key Dialog will open up . Mark always option and then you can see the device online.

Comment: thanks for the reply. while i have done that already, the adb version is 1.0.31, sdk version is 22.0.1. And the Developer Option is already on for the usb debug is in that setting. Also, i have reboot my phone and computer to make sure all these working. I dont know why, i had done these before in my office computer and it works fine.....very strange

Answer (score -1):

If you have android studio on your computer, you can see RSA dialog via android studio.

1. Open Android Studio
2. Run a project
3. Select the device you want

then RSA diolog screen appears on your device.