# Eclipse does not recognize my Android devices

Tags: android, eclipse

I have two Android devices connected to my computer by USB cable. In both devices I have enabled the USB debugging option. I also have the Google ADT plug-in installed.

However, in Eclipse's Devices view I do not see the devices listed.

My devices:

- Google Nexus 7 tablet
- LG-E430 smartphone

Comment: Lets get things straight: Worklight does not manage your devices. at all. It is your PC or Eclipse that does not recognize the devices correctly. Edit the question with details about the devices: brand, model, OS, Windows? Mac? etc...

Comment: But my PC recognizes them very well. The tablet is an Google Nexus 7 and the phone is a LG-E430.

Comment: That's great for your PC, still not a Worklight issue. ;)

Comment: That answer is not very helpful...

Comment: You mean my comment? it was a jest...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this question about Nexus 7 devices not being recognized by Eclipse: [Not seeing Nexus7 in Eclipse's Android Devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11533228/not-seeing-nexus7-in-eclipses-android-devices)

From the accepted answer:

> Heres what I did to get it working:
>
> 1. I happened to already have ADB drivers for the Samsung Galaxy Nexus installed, if you don't, you need to download those.
> 2. Plug in the Nexus 7 and windows will find 2 drivers automatically, but won't find any for "Nexus"
> 3. Go to Device Manager, under "Other Devices" you'll see "Nexus" with the yellow exclamation mark, Right Click>Upate Drivers>Let me
>      choose>Let me pick form device drivers on my computer.
> 4. Scroll down to "SAMSUNG Android Phone" (Again, the Galaxy Nexus drivers should be installed already, if not, find them), and choose
>      the driver for "Android ADB Interface"
> 5. Click "Next", and the device should pop up in Eclipse.
>
> It worked for me, at least.

Comment: yes, I've installed drivers for Nexus and Worklight recognized the device immediately. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need appropriate drivers for each of your android devices, the usual Windows' drivers aren't enough for debugging.

If you are using Nexus devices follow [these steps](http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html). *(Presuming you have a Nexus tablet)*

For a full list of OEM drivers which are required to perform adb debugging check [the official android developer site.](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html) *(For your LG device)*

Comment: Please refrain from using Link-Only answers, as links to external sites die, and when they do, this answer becomes non-helpful.